# What's normal/safe behavior for a 48V/1200W switching power supply?

Tags: power-supply, safety

When I unplug my 48V/1200W switching power supply, with no load, it reads a full 48V at the output for 5 seconds before there is a "click", and the voltage starts to drop. It takes another 30 seconds to reach 24V at the output, in a long slow bleed.

Is this safe and normal? Or is this power supply poorly designed and unsafe?

If this is normal, are there safety improvements I can make around it? I was thinking of adding an external fast bleed resistor on the outputs. I could switch that on one side of a DPDT switch that also switched the line wire from the input, choosing one of those to be connected at a time. That leaves the neutral wire unswitched, but I gather that is acceptable. An alternative is adding my own always-on bleed resistor, but it seems I will need several watts to make any meaningful difference in the decay time.

For context, I am a mechanical engineering student trying to power a robot motor for a project. The motor drive peaks at 48V/1000W, so I've tried to find a supply to suit that. I bought a [very cheap mystery brand off of Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0C591QLNR) that is 48V/1200W. I've wired it up to a 3-prong pigtail to my US standard plug. It does, indeed, deliver 48V. So far I haven't hooked it up to any meaningful load; just turned the supply on. I know these kinds of supplies are intended to be built into other machines that can render it safe for the user... but I have a hard time imagining a machine that is okay with 30 seconds to turn off. I made a pretty big spark when I experimented with shorting the output, making me think that I would not enjoy that shock through my body.

Comment: You don't say what country you're in, but be aware that your supply doesn't seem to be marked with the appropriate safety marks for North America. The CE mark indicates compliance with European safety standards, but it is self-certified and might not be verified by a third-party test lab.

Comment: Sounds like expected operation. In a mechanical sense the output capacitors are like a flywheel- they’ve spun upto speed but with no load there’s nothing to slow it down apart from some small amount of friction. You could have a relay switch a load on power fail or simply disconnect the output which is what would normally be done for an emergency stop safety circuit. Depending on your local electrical codes, it may not be necessary to switch neutral. It was not clear what you meant by this.

Comment: @ThePhoton In the US (hence the US-standard plug). Good point on safety marks. I don't think I'd trust that they're in compliance regardless of how many marks they put on it.

Comment: @Kartman I've dropped the switch plan in favor of an always-on resistor around 1W. I'm hoping that some normal operating load will also help drain it.

Comment: @RaveTheTadpole, if they had UL or UR (probably same at CSA, Intertek, etc.) there would be a file number and you could look it up at the agency instead of just trusting the mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything that charges a capacitor and does not discharge it will make the capacitor voltage drop very slowly.

So yes, it might be normal, or it might not be. I suppose you received no specifications with the power supply how it should work.

If you think this is a safety issue, you decide how long it is acceptable for the supply output to bleed out. But there will also be energy stored in the mains side, which is why it takes so long for the output to even start discharging without any load.

You could add a circuit or relay to discharge it faster, but it will also discharge faster when you do have some load there.

Also, don't short the output deliberately. It's not safe. And you can't get that jolt through your body, not at 48V DC, that's perfectly safe to touch. If you trust the cheap unbranded mystery power supply to even be able to pass the safety regulations of your jurisdiction to begin with.

Do not to wire main AC with the DC bleed resistor. Switching them with the same switch is a hazard if the switch breaks. Another hazard is that if you think the one switch pole cuts the live wire, it does no provide safety if someone has wired your socket wrong and has live and neutral swapped. That might be rare. In countries with unpolarized mains plugs, either wire can be live or neutral, so it would be unsafe to switch only one mains wire and for safety always both wires are treated like live and both are switched.

Comment: You can get a jolt from 48 volts, but it depends upon conditions, such as the moisture in/on your skin.

Comment: Thanks. I've dropped my idea of the DPDT switch to turn on a load, and I plan on adding 1W of always-on bleed to make it faster. Certainly no specs received, though I don't see anything about capacitor bleed rate on brand name models either.

Answer (score 2):

48 V is considered "inherently safe" by many safety standards. Applying 48 V across your body is very unlikely to injure you, unless you have a medical condition that makes you particularly susceptible to very small currents through the body.

If the output voltage for some reason rises above 48 V after the power is disconnected, then there could be cause for concern.

> I made a pretty big spark when I experimented with shorting the output, making me think that I would not enjoy that shock through my body.

Your body has a much higher resistance (typically at least 100 kohms for any path through the body that would go through the heart) than the short circuit does, so the currents that this 48 V supply would deliver to your body are much lower than what is produced when you short the outputs with a wire.

Comment: Thanks. I think the consensus is that it is very unlikely to kill me. It's less clear whether it would be very unpleasant or a non-event. I plan on not finding out.

Comment: @RaveTheTadpole, I took a safety engineering course where they applied 48 V between two points on my forearm. Gives a mild tingle. I wouldn't do it with broken skin, directly across the heart, or if I wore a pacemaker, etc., but on dry skin away from the heart its just noticeable.